# Slim 2 to Slim 3 method error

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to convert a slim 2 project to slim 3.
I am stucking with a problem.

When  I call my method:
http://localhost:8000/task_manager/v1/tasks

I get the next error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to authenticate() must 
be an instance of Slim\Route, instance of 
Slim\Http\Request given in 
C:\wamp64\www\task_manager\v1\index.php on line 42.
```

How could I fix it? Some help will be appreciated.

Here is my php code:

```
$app = new  \Slim\App();
...
...

function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
    // Getting request headers

    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $data = array();
    $app = AppContainer::getInstance();

    // Verifying Authorization Header
    if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // get the api key
        $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
        // validating api key
        if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
            // api key is not present in users table
            $data["error"] = true;
            $data["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
            return echoRespnse(401, $data, $response);
            //$app->stop();
            return $response->withStatus(401)->withBody("Bad Request");
        } else {
            global $user_id;
            // get user primary key id
            $user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);
        }
    } else {
        // api key is missing in header
        $data["error"] = true;
        $data["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
        return echoRespnse(400, $data, $response);
    }
}


$app->get('/tasks', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
            global $user_id;
            $data = array();
            $db = new DbHandler();

            // fetching all user tasks
            $result = $db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);

            $data["error"] = false;
            $data["tasks"] = array();

            // looping through result and preparing tasks array
            while ($task = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $tmp = array();
                $tmp["id"] = $task["id"];
                $tmp["task"] = $task["task"];
                $tmp["status"] = $task["status"];
                $tmp["createdAt"] = $task["created_at"];
                array_push($data["tasks"], $tmp);
            }

            return echoRespnse(200, $data, $response);
        })->add('authenticate');
```

Comment: Since you're not using `$route` anywhere in your `authenticate()` function, just change the `authenticate(\Slim\Route $route)` to `authenticate(Request $request, Response $response)`.

Comment: If you do the above, you can remove the `apache_request_headers()` and use Slim's Request class to fetch them instead: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html

Comment: Thank you. I think you are sure. It is an option to solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I am trying to do it, but How do I call authenticate method into "/tasks"

Comment: just authenticate($request, $response);?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Slim2 you could add middleware like this:

```
<?php
$aBitOfInfo = function (\Slim\Route $route) {
    echo "Current route is " . $route->getName();
};

$app->get('/foo', $aBitOfInfo, function () {
    echo "foo";
});
```

This is not possible in slim3: first the middleware must be added with the `add` method like this:

```
$app->get('/foo', function () {
    echo "foo";
})->add($aBitOfInfo);
```

Secondly middleware doesn't have the `\Slim\Route`-Object as first parameter.
These are not the [`Request`](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html), [`Response`](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html) and the callable of the next middleware. So this should be like this:

```
/**
 * Example middleware closure
 *
 * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request  PSR7 request
 * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface      $response PSR7 response
 * @param  callable                                 $next     Next middleware
 *
 * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
 */
$aBitOfInfo = function ($request, $response, $next) {
    $response->getBody()->write('BEFORE');
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $response->getBody()->write('AFTER');

    return $response;
};
```

<sup>(Source https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html)</sup>